# How do I write the link from front-page.php to home.php?

Tags: urls, links

Sorry for this, but I really combed everything there is on the subject and cannot come to the solution, although it is probably super-simple:

I have a front-page.php set as the static front page of the WordPress site.
In it there is a link that I'd like to link to the home.php or index.php.

How do I write the url?

```
<a  href='<?php echo esc_url( home_url()); ?>' title='<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ); ?>' rel='home'>
```

What do i write instead of *home_url()* , which lands me of course on the front-page.php ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There really should be a simpler way to do it but you kind of need to know that WordPress stores both the Front Page ID and Blog Page ID in the options table. So, to get the URL of the blog you need to use both [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) and [`get_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) in conjunction.

```
<a href='<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) ); ?>' title='<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ); ?>' rel='home'>Blog Page</a>
```

The above will grab `page_for_posts` value from the options table which holds the Page ID of the blog which needs to be set in `Settings -> Readings`. By passing an ID to `get_permalink()` it will return the string URL that we need for the page.

Comment: Yes, you say it! There really should be a way to do this!
I have spent a week now looking for a solution...
 
Thank you for your answer - it's completely logical, and i have also thought that `'page_for_posts'`  should be a part of the solution, alas! 
This returns me to the site's starting page.
It's a mess. 

  :/

Comment: @furby Have you set a blog page in `Settings -> Reading` along with your Front Page? I believe when you set one you _have_ to set the other.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to close this question, first of all - thank you, @Howdy_McGee!
You were on the right track, and the solution that works is

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ); ?>">Blog Page</a>
```

The `esc_url` is not doing the job here. I'm not that apt of a developer to know why, though I'd love to. 
Thank you again!